# condition for loading storyboard for iphone 6 without autolayout

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode

is it work for iphone 6 in potrait view without autolayout?

```
CGRect screenBounds = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
     if (screenBounds.size.height >= 568) {
     // code for iphone5 and iphone 6 is it work for different frame etc set? 
     }
     else {
     // code for iphone4
     }
```

Comment: It will work. Why don't you just try? You can try this on simulator.

Comment: in any device? i dont have updated version of Xcode that supports iphone6
Is it work for iphone6 too?

Comment: Yes it works and you have to update your Xcode to use iOS SDK8. It's not an optional to release your app to App Store.

Comment: Yes it 2GB RAM,is it will effect the speed ?

Answer (score 1):

```
if(UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone){
        if ([[UIScreen mainScreen] respondsToSelector: @selector(scale)]) {
            CGSize result = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size;
            result = CGSizeMake(result.width * scale, result.height * scale);

            if(result.height == 960) {
                iPhone 4s Retina
            }
            if(result.height == 1136) {
                //iPhone 5 & 6
            }
        }
        else{
            //Normal iPhone 3g,3gs
        }
    }
```